# Regex working online but not working in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to replace multiple spaces between quoted terms to single space, i.e. from:

```
Test line "one"            "two"            "three".
```

to:

```
Test line "one" "two" "three".
```

I have tried:

```
:%s/"[ ]+"/" "/g
:%s/"[\space]+"/" "/g
```

Though above work in online regex tester (https://regex101.com/) but they do not work in gvim. Where is the problem and how can it be corrected? Thanks.

Comment: try using `\s+` replace with `/ /`

Comment: I am still getting "pattern not found".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
:%s/\v\s+/ /g
```

`\v` is "very magic" mode. I include this for consistency, otherwise the expression would behave differently depending on your setting for `magic`.

`\s+` will match any contiguous block of whitespace. The replacement is a single space. The net result is to collapse any contiguous block of whitespace to a single space.

Note: If you have `gdefault` set, the above will not work (because in that case, the `g` flag disables the normal behavior). So if you have set `gdefault`, don't use the `g`.

### About "very magic"

Since it came up in comments I will elaborate a little on this. Vim has the notion of "magic" or "nomagic" mode. You can read more about this in `:help 'magic` if you want to, I don't want to write a long post about the topic here.

The short version is, depending what the setting is, things behave differently. So it is often helpful to use a specific mode, particularly in places like stackoverflow, where future readers will come along, and you have no idea what their settings might be.

So using a specific mode is beneficial IMO. This is the definition of "very magic" mode:

> Use of `\v` means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
>   `0`-`9`, `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z` and `_` have a special meaning.  "very magic"

This is (IMO) really predictable - it is easy to remember which characters can have a special meaning by default, and which don't. It also more cleanly lines up with the regexes people are used to from many programming languages. For example:

- `\s` - Use the backslash, because it's alphanumeric
- `+` or `*` - No backslash needed, not alphanumeric
- `( )` (grouping) or `[ ]` (character classes) - No backslash needed, these are not alphanumeric

It is more likely a person familiar with regex will try `\s+` than `\s\+`. Or that they will try `[0-9]*` than `\[0-9\]\*`. So very magic mode just seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: Actually, in my case, it works with 'g' at end, and does not work without it. Why do you think that is happening? How can I find the magic setting in my case? What should I keep the setting to?

Comment: @mso That's because I forgot I have `gdefault` active. I corrected my answer. You can see your setting for `magic` with `:set magic?` but if you use `\v` in the expression, the setting doesn't matter; `\v` will override the setting anyway. That's why I put it there, so you wouldn't have to care what it's set to.

Answer (score 2):

I found that `'+'` is being seen as a literal character. It should be `'\+'`. Now both following versions work:

```
%s/ \+/ /g
%s/\s\+/ /g
```

Comment: FWIW, whether `+` needs the `\ ` or not depends on the current setting of `magic`. (Which is why I used `\v` so that the setting of `magic` was not a variable.)

Comment: It seems that I should use \v always in vim. Is that correct?

Comment: @mso I updated my answer with some more info about very magic mode, to answer your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**This replaces multiple spaces between quoted terms to single space**

```
:%s/" \+"/" "/g
```

**Before**

```
Test line "one"            "two"            "three".
Alpha     "Preserve    internal   spacing"       "alpha    beta" "blow   fish"
This    line has no  quotes
```

**After**

```
Test line "one" "two" "three".
Alpha     "Preserve    internal   spacing" "alpha    beta" "blow   fish"
This    line has no  quotes
```

---

If you want to replace tabs as well as spaces, use `:%s/"\s\+"/" "/g`